# Convert elements of list to dataframe keeping column names unchanged

Tags: r, list

I have a list with several elements in it. I want to convert these elements to separated dataframes. However, I dont know how to retain column names. Please see the code below.

```
for (i in 1: length(mylist)) {
 assign(paste("df_",names(mylist[i]),sep = ""), as.data.frame(data.frame(mylist[i]),
col.names = names(dfi)))
}
names(df_april)

> names(df_april)
[1] "april.X"              "april.Latitude"       "april.month"          "april.count1"         "april.AOT40_1"        "april.count_full"    
[7] "april.AOT40_2"        "april.State.Code"     "april.County.Code"    "april.Longitude"      "april.Datum"          "april.Parameter.Name"
[13] "april.State.Name"     "april.County.Name"    "april.year"           "april.method"
```

As you can see above, I tried to use `as.data.frame` with defined `col.names = names(dfi)` to get rid of "april" in those column names. But it did not work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OP's code, change the `[` to `[[` as the first is still a `list` of length 1 and have a list name as well, while the second `[[` extracts the list element.  So, naturally, when we do the `as.data.frame`, the `list` element names also gets appended while flattening that element

```
for (i in seq_along(mylist)) {
    assign(paste("df_",names(mylist[[i]]),sep = ""), mylist[[i]],
         col.names = names(dfi)))
  }
names(df_april)
```

NOTE: It is better not to create mutiple objects in the global env.

Comment: Problem still there. The question is after I convert the element to a dataframe, how should I retain names in dataframe? I am not trying to name the elements in the list.

Comment: The thing is I need to do some manipulation after I convert list elements to dataframes. Those manipulation cannot be done on list element like `mylist2[[1]]`.

Comment: That's amazing. Thanks a ton. I just realized the difference between `mylist[1]` and `mylist[[1]]`.